# Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I need to edit data in my tables at Heroku, how can i do that with an IDE for PostgreSQL or some other solution to this? I'm really new to Heroku, so please can you guide me what's the best way around it.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Heroku does not offer direct access to the database. Does `heroku console` cut it for you? You can access the db through your models directly.

Otherwise you may want to look at how to [import/export your database](http://docs.heroku.com/taps).

Comment: So how do i execute my queries? i need to do a small change to the database, how do i do it?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of the thing you want to do with the db.

Comment: I want to update a users role without writing a migration, just a temporary update

Comment: Get into the console and just go through normal ActiveRecord methods. Probably something like `User.find(45).update_attributes(:role => :admin)`

Comment: the app uses cancan so how do i update cancan based user roles?

Comment: Cancan does not have preset roles, that should depend on how you have defined your roles.

Comment: so how can i get the roles that are in cancan?

Comment: It doesn't have any, except the ones you have defined yourself :) In fact it doesn't even define roles. You define your roles your way and cancan describes and handles what they can or cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a dedicated database, you will be able to take advantage of the "ingress" feature to get a raw connection to your database, compatible with all programs that need to speak over the Postgres wire protocol (examples include: psql, pgadmin, navicat, or Microsoft Excel with ODBC -- yes, really, and it's not half bad sometimes!)

But on shared databases you are somewhat out of luck at this time unless you somehow bounce your interactions off ruby and the pg gem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (if you're able to) use db:pull to bring the database locally, do the work locally and then db:push it back up.

Or more likely the easiest option is to do it from console (heroku console at prompt)

John.

Answer (score 0):

for my rails app I use the typus gem which provides a very simple to implement fairly nice db admin interface to the application.